# Сравнение строк python

Tags: python, циклы, сравнение

Почему цикл не выводит единицу? Ведь строчки одинаковые
Код:

```
f_read = open("C:\logs.txt", "r")
last_line = f_read.readlines()[-1]
f_read = open("C:\logs.txt", "r")
prelast_line = f_read.readlines()[-2]
print(prelast_line, end='')
print(last_line)
if prelast_line == last_line:
    print(1)
else:
    print(last_line)
```

Вывод:

```
6798: Нет открытых позиций
6798: Нет открытых позиций
6798: Нет открытых позиций

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Первые две строчки это принт, и он должен написать единицу, так как они одинаковые, но почему-то не так. В чем может быть проблема?

```
print(prelast_line == last_line)
```

Выводит false(

Comment: Покажите `print(repr(prelast_line))` и `print(repr(last_line))`

Comment: Предположу, что у вас в последней строке нет перевода строки, а в предпоследней есть. Используйте метод `strip()`

Answer (score 0):

Всё дело в символе переноса строки:

```
f_read = open("logs.txt", "r")
last_line = f_read.readlines()[-1]
last_line = last_line.rstrip('\n')
f_read = open("logs.txt", "r")
prelast_line = f_read.readlines()[-2]
prelast_line = prelast_line.rstrip('\n')
print("prelast_line: " + prelast_line)
print("last_line: " + last_line)
if prelast_line == last_line:
    print(1)
else:
    print(last_line)
```